# Preemptive authorization in Delphi with Indy or Soap

Tags: http, soap, indy, delphi-xe

I would like to make a preemptive authorization to a server, but I cannot find any solution for this in Delphi.
Please share your solution if You have one.

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required
<!doctype html public "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">  
<html>
    <head><title>401 Authorization Required</title></head>  
    <body>
        <h1> 401 Authorization Required </h1>
        <hr>
        <address>SQLAnywhere/12.0.1.4436</address>
    </body>
</html>
```

Regards, Tamas

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "***preemptive** authorization*", please clarify what your actual goal is.  401 is how an HTTP server asks a client for authentication credentials. Are you making an HTTP request to a server? There are plenty of HTTP client libraries/APIs available for Delphi.

Comment: The problem was i got a bad user name and pwd for the project so its solved now :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was i got a bad user name and pwd for the project so its solved now :)